# Change PhpMyAdmin Cookie Path

Tags: php, session, cookies, phpmyadmin

PhpMyAdmin sets the cookie path to the path PMA is installed in.

- So if it is installed in */pma/* it will set the cookie path to */pma/*.

However, I have logout code which needs to access the session to be able to log the user out of PMA along with other system sessions, but it is located in */*.

This of course does not work since the browser will not allow the cookie to be accessed outside of the cookie path.

Setting the default cookie path in php.ini does not work since PMA specifies its own path when setting the cookie which will override the php.ini setting.

Is there a way I can change the default cookie path set by PMA to */* by setting a config option or possibly extending a PMA class? I've also read about a thing called monkey patching using [runkit](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php), can it do that? If so how?

Editing PMA core files is not an option as I want the change to stick between upgrades. If this can be coded into config.inc.php it would stick between upgrades.

Some things I have tried via config.inc.php :

- setting my own cookie with same name and sessionid, does not work as cookie is overwritten by the one PMA sets further in the PHP processing.
- Changing the value of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] which is one of the values used in determining path, does not work, not sure why.
- I tried to extend the PMA_Config class particularly the getCookiePath() method, did not work as I don't know how to instantiate it so it overrides the PMA_Config's method.

Comment: I would consider `runkit` a bit over the top for that. Why don't you just hack the place where the string is originating from and so just patch the application to fulfill your needs if it does not provide the configuration option you're looking for? Add it as a configuration option and file a feature request with your patch then.

Comment: Also it looks like you're looking for SingleSignOn which is supported by PMA. Look in the docs what the existing options are: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types

Comment: whoa, didn't think people would respond so soon. I'm actually in the midst of setting up SSO already =o)

Comment: @hakre Got SSO to work, I had spent a week trying to figure out how to get by this and all I needed was to use different authtype. Since you did respond with a correct solution, would you want to put it as an answer with an explanation on how to set it up?

Comment: I have a better suggestion: Answer your own question. That's totally valid and I bet you can write a better answer than I am able to. I was just giving some pointers, that was all ;). And yes, it's totally accepted on this site that you answer your own questions. Good to read you solved it now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Signon authtype](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types#signon) for PMA

My PMA config then became:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'signon';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'YOUR_SESSION_ID'; // You can use ini_get('session_name') if you prefer
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL']     = 'FULL_URL'; // URL it will redirect unauthenticated users
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LogoutURL']     = 'FULL_URL'; // URL where user will be redirected after logout
```

In my SSO script, I added these lines when logging into the rest of the system so it will simultaneously login to PMA as well.

```
$_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_user'] = 'MY_PMA_USERNAME';
$_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_password'] = 'MY_PMA_PASSWORD';
```

Now I don't require having to access PMA cookie as it uses the SID cookie set by main system. To logout of main system and PMA I do a regular cookie logout:

```
$_SESSION = array();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 3600);
session_destroy();
```